# Genexus: Foreign Kay IsValid event not triggered on Web Transaction Gx X Ev3

Tags: events, web, transactions, genexus

I have this Transaction

```
Invoice
*InvoiceNumber
CustomerCode
CustomerName
...
```

In the Invoice Transaction, I have this event:

```
Event CustomerCode.IsValid
Msg("CustomerCode")
EndEvent
```

But It doesn't triggered and I don't know why

Note:
The event Triggers right

```
Event InvoiceNumber.IsValid
Msg("InvoiceNumber")
EndEvent
```

Thanks a lot, Ariel

Answer (score 0):

The event "IsValid" only triggers if the content changes (and you change it editing the control), so, if you let it blank it won't show the msg.
And, are you sure the control you have in the web form is "CustomerCode"?

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your help. I'm testing the events changing the value and the control I have is CustomerCode, is the Transaction Web Form generated by Genexus

Comment: I think you can have problems if CustomerCode is your last enabled control. Is there any button below CustomerCode?

Comment: Sorry, after CustomerCode are a lot of fields

Comment: Have you got rules? Why don't you comment all other Events and Rules to see if there is code that makes your event not to work?

Comment: I think I have a workarround to this problem. I created a SugGroup for the Customer and with this new fields the IsValid event is triggered. I think is a bug with the foreign key attributes